# Performance of page load with multiple scripts and HTTP multiplexing

Tags: javascript, http2, pageload, page-load-time, multiplexing

Given that the questions in this regard in this forum are > 3 years old, we were wondering about the most up-to-date response to this.

The main question is; how much performance do you still gain nowadays with the bundling of your ECMAScript Module files into one single js output file, mainly considering that HTTP/2 is now pretty much the browser standard, hence with multiplexing being the standard way of loading pages nowadays?

Our page load in some projects is somewhat slow, and we're wondering if it's worth it to bundle all of the page's js into a single js output file to boost performance, even if all the connections in the network tab normally use HTTP/2, and we can see that multiple connection channels open simultaneously. The pages of these projects in average load about 15-30 ECMAScript Modules, and the page uses no images or other things which could make us think cause performance issues. The Google Lighthouse Test in Chrome also does not show any bad note regarding page load performance.